# PHP not working when called on from JS

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to everything Javascript and PHP so I will try to be as clear as possible.

I have written a PHP file, which is working perfectly when I open it directly in my browser. However when I call on the PHP file from my JS , it doesn't work.

This is the PHP:

```
<?php
// remove the headers at start for a reset
header_remove("Content-type");
header_remove("Content-Disposition");

// here comes everything that will be in $myfile

header("Content-type: application/gpx+xml");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=route.gpx");

echo $myfile;

?>
```

This is what I am using to call the PHP file in JS:

```
function fuDownload(){

$.get('phpfile.php');
}
```

The fuDownload function is called when clicked on a button.

Comment: Show us your HTML code.

Comment: what does your chrome debugger's network traffic tell you? Are you getting a 404? If you are getting a 200, then check the content. If the content looks then most likely you are just not dumping the content into the DOM.

Comment: I am getting a 200. I have not put anything in my HTML concerning this file. I am looking into the DOM thing you said. I have no experience with this. If you have any tips on what to do, they are much apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your trying to generate a file using headers then $.get isn't the right function.

Try:

```
  window.location.href = 'phpfile.php';
```

You should use $.get to interact with the DOM at add elements to it, but header() must be called before any actual output is sent, which in your case ( assuming your just trying to automatically start a download) a standard link will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
```

`$.get( "test.php" );` requests the test.php page, but ignore the return results.

use `$.get( "test.php", function( data ) { ... } )`,
 `$.get( "test.php" ).done(function( data ) { ... });`
 or `$( "#result" ).load( "test.php" );`(http://api.jquery.com/load/)